# Uneven automated buckets/bins in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, aggregate-functions, bucket

ads Table:
-one row per ad per day

```
date    |   ad_id  | account_id | spend  
2018-05-01   123     1101        100  
2018-05-02   123     1101        125  
2018-05-03   124     1101        150  
2018-05-04   124     1101        150    
2018-05-04   125     1105        150  
2018-05-04   126     1105        150  
2018-05-04   123     1101        150  
2018-01-01   123     1101        150
```

I am trying to create a histogram to show the how much advertisers have spent in last 7 days.
I want the first bucket to be $10-999.99 and others to be $1000-1999.99,$2000-2999.99 etc but this I want to achieve through automation not by manually mentioning buckets through case function.

My current code does well in creating even automated buckets:

```
select CONCAT(1000*FLOOR(last_7_days_spend/1000), "-", 1000*FLOOR(last_7_days_spend/1000)+999.99) "spend($)" , count(*) "frequency"
from
(select account_id, sum(spend) "last_7_days_spend"
from fb_ads
where date between date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day) and date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
group by account_id) as abc
group by 1
order by 1;
```

and it returns this:

```
spend       |   frequency
0-999.99        2  
2000-2999.99    1
```

But want to write some similar kind of query which should filter out records and start from $10-999.99  instead of $0.00-999.99.
Desired output:

```
spend       |   frequency  
10-999.99       2  
2000-2999.99    1
```

Comment: You'll need to use a case expression to define the first bucket.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for commenting. How would I use the case function to create the first bucket and then in the same column automate it for the rest of the buckets?
Could you show some example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a `CASE` expression to define the first bucket, but you can automate the other buckets within that expression. Note that if you don't want a bucket for a spend of less than $10, you'll need to filter those values out:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN last_7_days_spend < 1000 THEN '10-999.99'
         ELSE CONCAT(1000*FLOOR(last_7_days_spend/1000), "-", 1000*FLOOR(last_7_days_spend/1000)+999.99)
    END AS `spend($)`,
    COUNT(*) AS `frequency`
FROM (
    SELECT account_id, SUM(spend) AS `last_7_days_spend`
    FROM fb_ads
    WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    GROUP BY account_id
) as abc
WHERE last_7_days_spend >= 10
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Small [demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/to7nV5r5vHeMwepj9at1Am/3)